# C# class only returning first item of a JavaScript array - cant update just one record of db

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a grid in html with some data of example Directors. Then I change the data, and want to update db.

Using a JS function, I get all the details from the grid, and save it in an array.

```
function getDirectorGridDetails() {
var tableRows = document.getElementById("tc_directorsGrid_table").rows
for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var directorRow = tableRows[i]

    if (directorRow) {
        var directorRowSeq = directorRow.getAttribute("data-id");
        var directorDetailDesc = directorRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
        var directorDetailGender = directorRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML;
        var directorDetailDateApp = directorRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML;
        var directorDetailDateRes = directorRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML;

        if (!x) {
            var x = [];
            var Seq = [];
            var Description = [];
            var Gender = [];
            var DateAppointed = [];
            var DateResigned = [];
        }

        Seq.push(directorRowSeq);
        Description.push(directorDetailDesc);
        Gender.push(directorDetailGender);
        DateAppointed.push(directorDetailDateApp);
        DateResigned.push(directorDetailDateRes);
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}

var directorsclass = {
    "directorsclass": {
        "Seq": Seq,
        "Description": Description,
        "Gender": Gender,
        "DateAppointed": DateAppointed,
        "DateResigned": DateResigned
    }
}
return directorsclass
};
```

then, when I enter my C# side, to get the details and update db, the class is only returning the first items of the array.

Is there a way of getting each object from array, pass that in to class?

c# code snippit

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("client/updateDirector")]
    public ActionResult updateDirector([System.Web.Http.FromBody] DirectorsClass directorsclass)
    {}
```

when it get to directorsclass, it only shows first element

Comment: with `var x = [];` you create every time a new array. So you have to move the array initialization outside the for loop.

Comment: only used var x, to avoid creating new arrays everytime. if I step through the code, it is getting all the info. @ return directorsclass, i have the arrays needed, with all the data. When I enter C# side, it is only the first item.

Comment: Can it be because C# is expecting an object, and I`m giving it an array?

Comment: If you step through can you see if the arrays you created everytime get more elements or are they containing only one element after the loop?

Comment: they getting more elements.
when I`m done with the loop, and look at the directorsclass (return directorsclass), it has all the elements

Comment: What is your c# code? how do you get the elements? can you add what you have done so far in your code to the question?

Comment: added the c# piece at beginning. making an ajax call to get data from js to c#